# Нет драйверов на видеокарту AMD R5 M230 для linux

Tags: linux, железо, amd, драйвер

Уже целый ден сижу и ищю дрова для дискретной видюхи , на видузятник есть , а на linux дров для это карты нету . Что делать ? Сидеть на инегрированной ?

Comment: Почему же сразу на интегрированной сидеть? Отреверсите вендовые и напишите линуховые дрова!

Comment: Вы плохо ищете, вот просто погуглите, полно же обсуждений!